# Python - Extract everything in a textfile after a certain string

Tags: python

I have a textfile, an interview. I am interested in extracting all the text after the words "Questions & Answers". How would I do this?

Comment: ...have you *tested* it?

Comment: Seeing as we don't have your file, you tell us. *Is it correct*?

Comment: Please use [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for questions about the correctness of working code.

Answer (score 0):

This would do it, you only need 2 lines:

```
f = open("interview.txt").read()
textAfter = f.split('Questions and Answers')[1]
```